# Laravel Dusk ignores Vue button

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, vuejs2, laravel-dusk

while testing Laravel + Vue, test compiling without errors, but ignores "->click()" method

dusk code

```
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->maximize()
                ->assertSee('Comments')
                ->value('#comment-form', 'ffs')
                ->click('@comment-add-0')
                ->pause(1000)
                ->assertSee('ffs');
```

comment form template

```
<form @submit.prevent="letsGo">
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment-form"
  v-model="commentReplyForm.body" v-focus placeholder="Write here :)"></textarea>
</div>
<button :dusk="getId()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Leave comment</button>
```

Comment: what is this identifier, `@comment-add-0`

Comment: getId() result of :dusk attribute
returns 'comment-add-' + parent_id